# What is the most mature MongoDB driver for C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm, mongodb-.net-driver

So, there are

- mongodb-csharp
- simple-mongodb
- NoRM

as C# drivers for MongoDB available.

Which one of them is the most mature and stable one?
Why would you choose one over the other two?

Are they production ready?

Comment: Just for the record: I chose NoRM as my default and I'm very happy with it so far.

Comment: Update: now there is an official MongoDB c# driver supported by MongoDB dev team: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center

Comment: I think NoRM is effectively dead at this time, until another maintainer can be found.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The mongodb-csharp driver is about to make a huge push regarding support for typedcollections which will include full Linq support.  I think you'll find that it is easy to work.

The other 2 projects are also steaming ahead.  If you want .NET 4.0 support, simple-mongodb would be your best bet.

NoRM has a whole bunch of committers who are all great coders, so no problem with it except it doesn't have an official release.

Comment: I would also mention that although we haven't "officially" released, we are very API stable, and I feel the driver is production quality.

Comment: Just to let everyone know. I talked to the developers of mongodb-csharp and there in maintenance mode right now. They recommend for any new projects to use the official MongoDB C# driver. MongoDB has really made a lot of progress on the driver and is a couple weeks a way from production 1.0 release.

Comment: Yes, it was made about 4 years ago.

Answer (score 21):

Since this question was answered 10gen have released an [official MongoDB C# driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial), and although it isn't the most mature C# driver in terms of age, with 10gen behind it it may end up as the most up to date.

It is more low level than the mongodb-csharp driver (no Linq support at the moment) but we haven't found that to be a problem. We moved to the official driver from mongodb-csharp recently on a project (that isn't in production yet) for the following reasons:

- Replica Set support in an official release
- SafeMode allows you to specify how many servers a write must be replicated to
- The driver handles connecting/disconnecting to the database
- We're hoping that as an official driver, it will have more developer support

Answer (score 8):

I'd go with [Sam Corder](http://twitter.com/samcorder)’s [mongodb-csharp](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp). Also checkout [this](http://deserialized.com/the-state-of-mongodb-and-csharp/) article.

Comment: We have really huge problems in Sam Corder driver in high traffic projects. never use Samus in big projects.

Answer (score 6):

For all curious out there. The best combination at this point seems to be official 10gen C# driver combined with fluent-mongo for Linq support:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

https://github.com/craiggwilson/fluent-mongo

Update: with release 1.4 of official C# driver, there'll be no need in fluent-mongo anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MongoDB.Driver from this [nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/).

You can view the full tutorials for the MongoC# example looking at this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x0-vHHHpv8

Answer (score 0):

A couple reasons to avoid the mongodb-csharp driver:

1. It doesn't support "or" logic.
2. It doesn't seem to support geospatial queries, at least we were not able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a performance issue in typed builders (Update<>, Query<>) of official 10gen C# driver. See [How to speed up typed builders in 10gen official MongoDB C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428938/how-to-speed-up-typed-builders-in-10gen-official-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)