# Id of Upserted Mongo Document in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, upsert

It has been well documented how to get a return Id from an Insert to a MongoDb collection in C# ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139887/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-the-rcently-inserted-document-after-an-insert-using-mongo)).  But how do I get that for an upserted document?  Is there a way, short of querying for the Id again, to use the SafeModeResult returned by an Update to find the upserted document Id?

```
My code:
var query = abc;
var update = xyz;
try
{
   db["Collection"].Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert);
}
catch
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

```
db["Collection"].FindAndModify(query, SortBy.Ascending(), update, true, true).Response.GetValue(1).AsBsonDocument.GetValue("_id")
```

returns the ObjectId.

Comment: So you know, `FindAndModify` is an atomic function, which means that if you are doing a lot of writes, it could be slow as it will lock the whole database for each write.  I don't *believe* mongo currently supports collection level locking, so if you run a lot of these, it may cause a slowdown.